# Trying to figure out how to access list in a different method

Tags: c#

This is my Code inside my Class. I'm trying to figure out how to access Questions list in  `DisplayQuestion`. I have a program.cs that display a menu for a quiz and I can't have anything static.

```
public string Question { get; set; }
public List<string> Choices { get; set; }
public char[] CorrectChoice = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
public List<string> Questions { get; set; }
```

These are my methods inside my class. I will need to access this list multiple times inside this class.

```
public void NewQuestion()
{
        Questions = new List<string>();
        Choices = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the question: ");
        Questions.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Choice 1 for the question:");
        Choices.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Choice 2 for the question: ");
        Choices.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Choice 3 for the question: ");
        Choices.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Choice 4 for the question:");
        Choices.Add(Console.ReadLine());
       // Console.WriteLine("Enter the correct choice(A,B,C,D)");


        foreach (string choice in Choices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(choice);
        }
    } 

    public void DisplayQuestions()
    {
       foreach(string question in Questions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(question);
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Little bit confused and unclear that what you are asking and what you are planning to do with this snippet, it would be great if you ask the question more specifically

Comment: Where is `public List<string> Questions { get; set; }` declared? In which class? And where is `public void DisplayQuestions()` declared?

Comment: i'm not seeing any problem in the above code if all of them in the same scope!

Comment: Code Snippet is ok ,but what actually you want to ask is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring and initializing it to null in the global section or create a class with proper getter setter methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel constrained to do everything in one class. Even a rough, verbose attempt at separating concerns into separate classes helps with readability, maintainability, and sanity. Then, you're just a thoughtful refactor away from good code.

You are using C#, an OBJECT-oriented language. So go with the grain and embrace using objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Quiz_StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var quizGenerator = new QuizGenerator();
            var quiz = quizGenerator.GenerateQuiz();
            var quizProctor = new QuizProctor();
            var grade = quizProctor.ProctorQuiz(quiz);
            Console.WriteLine(grade.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Done. Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class QuizGenerator
    {
        public Quiz GenerateQuiz()
        {
            var problems = GenerateProblems();
            var quiz = new Quiz()
            {
                Problems = problems
            };
            return quiz;
        }

        private List<Problem> GenerateProblems()
        {
            List<Problem> problems = new List<Problem>();
            int numChoices = InputValidator.GetPositiveNumber("Enter number of problems:  ");
            for (int i = 0; i < numChoices; i++)
            {
                Problem problem = GenerateProblem();
                problems.Add(problem);
            }
            return problems;
        }

        private Problem GenerateProblem()
        {
            var question = GenerateQuestion();
            var choices = GenerateChoices();
            var answer = GenerateAnswer(choices);
            var problem = new Problem()
            {
                Question = question,
                Choices = choices,
                Answer = answer
            };
            return problem;
        }

        private string GenerateQuestion()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the question: ");
            string question = Console.ReadLine();
            return question;
        }

        private List<string> GenerateChoices()
        {
            List<string> choices = new List<string>();
            int numChoices = InputValidator.GetPositiveNumber("Enter number of choices for the question:  ");
            for (int i=1; i<=numChoices; i++)
            {
                string choice = GenerateChoice(i);
                choices.Add(choice);
            }
            return choices;
        }

        private string GenerateChoice(int index)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Enter Choice {index} for the question: ");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            return choice;
        }

        private Answer GenerateAnswer(List<string> choices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the answer: ");
            string userChoice = InputValidator.GetUserChoice(new Problem() { Choices=choices });
            var answer = new Answer()
            {
                Value = userChoice
            };
            return answer;
        }
    }

    public class QuizProctor
    {
        public Grade ProctorQuiz(Quiz quiz)
        {
            var answers = new List<Answer>();
            foreach(Problem problem in quiz.Problems)
            {
                Answer answer = ProctorProblem(problem);
                answers.Add(answer);
            }
            Grade grade = quiz.Grade(answers);
            return grade;
        }

        private Answer ProctorProblem(Problem problem)
        {
            string userChoice = InputValidator.GetUserChoice(problem);
            var answer = new Answer()
            {
                Value = userChoice
            };
            return answer;
        }
    }

    public class Quiz
    {
        public List<Problem> Problems { get; set; }

        public Grade Grade(List<Answer> answers)
        {
            List<Answer> answerKey = Problems.Select(x => x.Answer).ToList();
            var rawResults = new List<Tuple<Answer, Answer>>();
            for(int i=0; i<answers.Count; i++)
            {
                Answer correct = answerKey[i];
                Answer provided = answers[i];
                rawResults.Add(new Tuple<Answer, Answer>(correct, provided));
            }
            return new Grade(rawResults);
        }
    }

    public class Grade
    {
        private List<Tuple<Answer, Answer>> RawResults { get; set; }
        public decimal Percent
        {
            get { return decimal.Divide(RawResults.Count(x => x.Item1.Equals(x.Item2)), RawResults.Count); }
        }

        public Grade(List<Tuple<Answer, Answer>> rawResults)
        {
            RawResults = rawResults;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("You scored a {0:P2}.", Percent);
        }
    }

    public class Problem
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public List<string> Choices { get; set; }
        public Answer Answer { get; set; }

        public string Prompt()
        {
            Func<int, char> numberToLetter = (int n) =>
            {
                return (char)('A' - 1 + n);
            };

            string prompt = Question;
            for (int i=0; i<Choices.Count; i++)
            {
                string choice = Choices[i];
                prompt += $"\n{numberToLetter(i+1)}) {choice}";
            }
            return prompt;
        }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value + "";
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }
            return (obj as Answer).Value.Equals(Value);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public static class InputValidator
    {
        public static int GetPositiveNumber(string prompt)
        {
            int number = -1;
            while (number < 0)
            {
                Console.Write(prompt);
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    number = int.Parse(input);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Please input a positive number.");
                }
            }
            return number;
        }

        public static string GetUserChoice(Problem problem)
        {
            Func<char, int> letterToNumber = (char c) =>
            {
                if (char.IsLower(c))
                {
                    return (int)(c - 'a' + 1);
                }
                return (int)(c - 'A' + 1);
            };

            char userChoiceLetter = '_';
            while (!char.IsLetter(userChoiceLetter))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(problem.Prompt());
                Console.Write("Answer:  ");
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    userChoiceLetter = char.Parse(input);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Please input a letter corresponding to your choice.");
                }
            }
            int answerIndex = letterToNumber(userChoiceLetter) - 1;
            return problem.Choices[answerIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that code respond in any way to the question whatever it is?